# Is converting decltype's expression from constant l-value into an r-value discards `const` too?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, decltype

Here I want to know how type specifier `decltype` works:

```
const int& rci = 5;// const ref bound to a temporary
decltype (rci) x = 2;
decltype (rci + 0) y = 10;
// ++x; // error: increment of read-only reference ‘x’|
++y; // why does this work

std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; // i
std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl; // i
```

- Why `y` has only type `int` rather than `const int`?
- Does converting a constant lvalue into an rvalue discards in addition to reference operator, `const` qualifier too?
- Why `typeid` shows that the type of `x` is just `i` but not `const int&`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**> Why y has only type int rather than const int?**

Because `(rci + 0)` is a prvalue, and prvalues of primitive types have const stripped.

**> Does converting a constant lvalue into an rvalue discards in addition to reference operator, const qualifier too?**

For non-class types, const qualifier is discarded. From the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#1.sentence-3):

> 7.3.1.1
>  [...] If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T.

**> Why typeid shows that the type of x is just i but not const int&?**

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, typeid(const T) == typeid(T)).

Comment: Upvoted - nice standard reference for the second point.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression you get when you add an `int` (`0` is an octal literal of type `int`) to a `const int&` is an `int`. So the type of `y` is an `int`.

On your second point, during an *lvalue to rvalue conversion*, `const` is discarded for non-class types as rvalues of non-class types cannot be cv-qualified.

On your last point, in all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by `typeid`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: @Maestro: Sorry on that point I was being a little facetious. The radix doesn't matter as zero is zero in any radix. But strictly speaking just like `07` is an octal literal, `0` is too. Note that `int a = 08;` is a compilation error therefore.

Comment: Ah you were mistaken. Adding a `0` into an `int`doesn't mean it makes it octal. But adding a `0` into a literal does.

Comment: @Maestro: A number is a number. 010 is the same as 8. It's just another way of specifying an `int`. It doesn't magically "octalise" an expression. E.g. 0 + 10 is still 10.